# Python networkx graph copy enters recursive loop and fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, copy, networkx

I'm posting this here both as an answer (to follow) and a question.

I am copying a graph to then trim certain edges, increment my path search, then trim and repeat (in a recursive, depth-first path search).

**Question:**

I understand lightly the difference between a shallow copy and a deepcopy, but can anyone enlighten me as to the consequences of the two when copying graphs?

My question arises because when using the networkx `copy` function:

```
G2 = G.copy()
```

which I believe creates a deepcopy, I entered a recursive copying loop which eventually failed (screenshot below). And I found that using a shallow copy:

```
G2 = nx.MultiDiGraph(G)
```

no such problems occurred. However I wonder if I am likely to need to use one over the other or if one is generally preferable?

**Deepcopy Problem:**

The deepcopy enters a recurvie copying loop and fails, why?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I eventually discovered, and I haven't seen anything along these lines mentioned anywhere else, hence my posting it here for others' future reference, that the origin of the problem was that **my node names were beautifulSoup NavigableStrings and not strings**.

My node names were generated by a function parsing some html with an created along the lines of:

```
(soup.find(class_='from').abbr.string, soup.find(class_='tp').abbr.string)
```

simply converting the NavigableStrings to strings fixed the problem:

```
(str(soup.find(class_='from').abbr.string), str(soup.find(class_='tp').abbr.string))
```